# problem with add library for hilt testing

Tags: android, testing, dagger-hilt

I use hilt for dependency injection.
I use this articles for implements test.
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing
https://dagger.dev/hilt/testing.html
now wanna write test for my fragments.
I have a problem with add library.

this is my code
this class is my runner and use in gradle

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(
        cl: ClassLoader?,
        className: String?,
        context: Context?
    ): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, MyCustom_Application::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

this is interface for hilt to generate an application class that i use in runner class

```
@CustomTestApplication(AndroidApplication::class)
interface MyCustom
```

this is my test class

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class SettingsActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    // UI tests here.

    @Test
    fun test(){
//        val activityScenario = launchActivity<MainActivity>()
    }
}
```

my libraries

```
// For instrumented tests.
androidTestImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.28-alpha")

// ...with Kotlin.
kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.34.1-beta")

androidTestImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2")
androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0")
```

but my problem:

when i add this line

```
kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.34.1-beta")
```

gradle show this error message:

```
error: SettingsActivityTest_TestComponentDataSupplier is not abstract and does not override abstract method get() in TestComponentDataSupplier
public final class SettingsActivityTest_TestComponentDataSupplier extends TestComponentDataSupplier {
             ^
```

and when i use this line

```
kaptTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.34.1-beta")
```

android studio cant generate MyCustom_Application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before. This problem occurs due to incompatibility of versions.

**use :**

```
androidTestImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.34.1-beta")
kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.34.1-beta")
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.34.1-beta") //hilt dependency
```

**instead of this :**

```
androidTestImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.28-alpha")
kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.34.1-beta")
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just as a heads up to others, Android Studio doesn't always highlight out-of-date dependencies.  In this case, I'd assumed that there wasn't a more recent version of the hilt-android-testing dependency, even though its version differed from other hilt dependencies I was using. But, after changing this library's version to match the others, the error described by the OP was fixed. In retrospect, I'd in the past updated only those dependencies highlighted by the IDE, which is how the versions became different in the first place.